# Kendo-Grid Filter textbox not working in Google Chrome but working in IE

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently I am working in Kendo-Grid. I'm kind of new in Kendo. In the grid, I'm having filter functionality. In that, I can filter the records in IE but that filter is not working in Google Chrome. I'm unable to write anything in text box in google chrome but that is working perfectly fine in IE. Please help me with this issue.

I have tried to put filterable:true but still it's not helping me.

```
$('#demo').kendoGrid({
             groupable: false,

             sortable: true,
             serverPaging: false,
             serverSorting: false,
             serverFiltering: true,
             resizable: false,
             persistSelection: true,
             scrollable:false,
             pageable: {
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 10
             },
             toolbar: ["excel"],
             excel: {
                fileName: "demo.xlsx",
                allPages: true
             },
             pdf: {
                 fileName: "demo.pdf",
                 allPages: true
             },
             dataSource: {
                 pageSize: 10
             },
             filterable: true,
             columns: [
                 {
                     type: "date",
                     format:"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" ,
                     field: "key",
                     title:"Date",
                     width: "29px" 
                 },

                 {
                     field:"prop",
                     title:"Pages",

                 },
                 {
                     field:"prop.length",
                     title:"View Count",
                      width: "29px",
                 }
             ]

        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

The textbox should be editable.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resolved my issue. The issue that, bootstrap modal in preventing the window element. So I have put this after popup of bootstrap modal.

```
            $(document).off('focusin.modal');
```

For more information, refer this link.
[KendoGrid Filter Issue](https://www.telerik.com/forums/column-menu-filter-input-box-not-selectable)